# Token module with slim framework api and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, token, slim

I have to implement authentication token in my application angularjs. I found 2 modules, ng-token-auth and Satellizer.

In the part of back-end I have an API with slim framework. Why should I decide which module that works well with slim framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heads up: Most moderators will mark such a question as not suitable for SO since it's related to selecting one of many libraries. Many time the choice is objective and causes negative responses.
With all that said, personally, after analyzing I chose Satellizer, since I was not aware of ng-token-auth. 
If I had to choose today I would probably go to the more feature rich ng-token-auth. To quote their site the advantages are clear:

Satellizer occupies the same problem domain as ng-token-auth. Advantages of ng-token-auth (at the time of this writing) include:

- Events. Seamless, out-of-the-box integration with the devise token
  auth gem. This gem provides a high level of security with minimal
  configuration.
- Auth header customization (GK: this is also supported in Satellizer).
- Auth response customization. Supports both cookies and localStorage for session persistence.(GK: this is also supported in Satellizer)
- Supports password reset and password update for users
  that registered by email.
- deletion.
- multiple user types.